# DynamoDB save to DB

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS and i'm trying to save data to my database using the aws example with News table.

I connected this function to the main storyboard button :

```
 @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

    //Create data object using data models you downloaded from Mobile Hub
    let newsItem: News = News();

    // Use AWSIdentityManager.default().identityId here to get the user identity id.
    newsItem._userId = "us-east-1:74c8f7ce-244b-4476-963e-0dcb3216f406"
    newsItem._articleId = "0123"
    newsItem._title = "Banana"
    newsItem._author = "Logan"
    newsItem._content = "Should I stay or should I go now?"
    newsItem._category = "Food"


    //Save a new item
    dynamoDbObjectMapper.save(newsItem, completionHandler: {
        (error: Error?) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            print("Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        print("An item was saved.")
    })

}
```

but when I hit the button I get :
`mazon DynamoDB Save Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException, message=Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes}`

my News fields are :

```
       override class func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable: Any] {
    return [
           "_userId" : "userId",
           "_articleId" : "articleId",
           "_author" : "author",
           "_category" : "category",
           "_content" : "content",
           "_title" : "title",
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are the required fields for the associated dynamoDB table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I solved adding @objc in eery variable from News(), for example

```
class News: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
    @objc var id: String?
    @objc var type: String?
    @objc var cc: String?
}
```

If you add @objc that force to wrap to NS Object, this is a bug for the aws mobile sdk...

Comment: This really helped me. Upvoting. Thanks!